/snap/snap-store/1218/gnome-platform/command-chain/desktop-launch not found: ensure slot is connected
Content snap command-chain for /snap/snap-store/1218/gnome-platform/command-chain/desktop-launch not found: ensure slot is connected

What command did you execute? Please add more context to your question.
